# MySQL DISTINCT more column

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a log table with about 500k rows.

Many of that rows are redundant (about 50 messages repeated again and again) so I want to group them by message content.

But the problem is that I work with MySQL 5.5 and InnoDB engine in this version does not support fulltext indexes. And I could not use MyISAM because I am working with foreign keys.

I tried this with ORDER BY clause but it took about 7 seconds.

When I tried that with DISTINCT(message) it was done in amazing 300ms but DISTINCT gives me just one column.

How should I build the SELECT with DISTINCT plus all the other columns like date, id but do not hurt performance?

Comment: can you create a composite unique index over the fields.

Comment: @bernd-buffen well I want that messages like they are I don't want them filtered on beginning.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @strawberry I designed it so. If there will be no solution for this problem I will have to port it into MyISAM finally

Comment: @Strawberry Now I realized that I have foreign key in it, so I could not go with MyISAM

Comment: Well, you could disregard the constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your message have a lot of repetition you may want to separate them out into a "look up" table. I guess if you can't put a UNIQUE index on the messages in this lookup table, you just need to enforce it in code as well as you can, or even do some cleanup from time to time.

```
messages
--------
id
user_id
date
...
text (INT FK to message_text.id)

message_text
------------
id
text
```

So then you would not be repeating the message text over and over, but several rows in `messages` could reference the same text.

Comment: Well I decided to make an UNIQUE index on date + message(100) so now I have only few logs in my look up table and I have better position to handle them. I also made an event to clean it up every 3 days. Many thanks to you dan08 and @Strawberry